# While opening an excel generated using Apache POI 5.2.5 getting a pop up "We found a problem with some content in abc.xlsx. *****"

Tags: excel, apache-poi

I created the going to generate the excel using Apache POI 5.2.5 and 4.1.2 both the version and I am getting the same pop up. The same code is running in the local system but when I try to run the code on server this error is coming.

"We found a problem with some content in abc.xlsx. Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can? If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes"

I tried only by creating the sheet and commented the other part but that is also failing.

```
            String excelPath = "C:\\Users\\aa.bb\\Desktop\\Test.xlsx";

    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    workbook.createSheet("Report");

    ByteArrayOutputStream b_Array_Out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    workbook.write(b_Array_Out);
    byte[] b_FileByte = b_Array_Out.toByteArray();
    
    File batchFile = new File(excelPath);
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(batchFile);
    fos.write(b_FileByte);
    fos.close();
```

[Error while opening excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJtmv.png)
[Jars used for excel generation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xoZ2I.png)

Can you please me is getting this issue resolved. I tried the same code for POI versions 3.17, 4.1.0, 4.1.1, 4.1.2 and 5.2.5 but everywhere is same error

Comment: An output stream needs to be closed when writing is done. Else the writing target may not be complete. So do `fos.close();` after `fos.write(b_FileByte);`.

Comment: I see you added `fos.close();` to you code. Now the error disappeared? If not, it is not reproducible using the provided code. What happens if you click `yes`? Excel then should tell you what had needed to be repaired. What was it?

Comment: Even after adding fos.close(); the error is not fixed. On clicking on Yes it do not show whats fixed

Comment: @AxelRichter - Can you please let me know the fix for this issue

Comment: It is not reproducible using the provided code. What happens if you click `yes`?

Comment: On Click on Yes it opens the excel but it does not repair anything as its a blank excel